# Enhancing performance using DataParallel

Tags: pytorch

I have written the following code to practice parallelizing a PyTorch code on GPUs:

```
import math
import torch
import pickle
import time

import numpy as np
import torch.optim as optim

from torch import nn

print('device_count()', torch.cuda.device_count())
for i in range(torch.cuda.device_count()):
    print('get_device_name', torch.cuda.get_device_name(i))

def _data(dimension, num_examples):
    num_mislabeled_examples = 20

    ground_truth_weights = np.random.normal(size=dimension) / math.sqrt(dimension)
    ground_truth_threshold = 0

    features = np.random.normal(size=(num_examples, dimension)).astype(
        np.float32) / math.sqrt(dimension)
    labels = (np.matmul(features, ground_truth_weights) >
              ground_truth_threshold).astype(np.float32)
    mislabeled_indices = np.random.choice(
        num_examples, num_mislabeled_examples, replace=False)
    labels[mislabeled_indices] = 1 - labels[mislabeled_indices]

    return torch.tensor(labels), torch.tensor(features)

class tools:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'x_2'

    def SomeFunc(self, model, input_):
        print(model.first_term(input_)[0])    # change to model.module.first_term when the flag is True


class predictor(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dim):
        super(predictor, self).__init__()
        self.weights = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(dim, 1, requires_grad=True))
        self.threshold = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(1, 1, requires_grad=True))

    def first_term(self, features):
        return features @ self.weights

    def forward(self, features):
        return self.first_term(features) - self.threshold

class HingeLoss(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(HingeLoss, self).__init__()
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, output, target):
        all_ones = torch.ones_like(target)
        labels = 2 * target - all_ones
        losses = all_ones - torch.mul(output.squeeze(1), labels)

        return torch.norm(self.relu(losses))

class function(object):
    def __init__(self, epochs):

        dim = 10
        N = 100
        self.target, self.features = _data(dim, N)

        self.epochs = epochs 
        self.model = predictor(dim).to('cuda')
        self.optimizer = optim.SGD(self.model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
        self.target = self.target.to('cuda')
        self.features = self.features.to('cuda')
        self.loss_function = HingeLoss().to('cuda')

        self.tools = tools()

    def train(self):

        self.model.train()
        for epoch in range(self.epochs):
            self.optimizer.zero_grad()
            output = self.model(self.features)
            # self.tools.SomeFunc(self.model, self.features)
            print(output.is_cuda)
            loss = self.loss_function(output, self.target)
            loss.backward()
            print('For epoch {}, loss is: {}.'.format(epoch, loss.item()))
            self.optimizer.step()

def main():
    model = function(1000)
    print(torch.cuda.device_count())
    if False: # This is Flag
        if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
            model.model = nn.DataParallel(model.model)
    t = time.time()
    model.train()
    print('elapsed: {}'.format(time.time() - t))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As far as I understand setting *the flag* to `True` should fix the thing, but my run time increases from 1 sec to 15 sec's. I was wondering how to improve the performance.